# F# fsi.AddPrinter: Does AddPrinter have ability to take list apart?

Tags: f#, fsi

In our [project](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples) we use `fsi.AddPrinter` for printing type `formula<fol>.`

To make it easier we include `fsi.AddPrinter sprint_fol_formula` in our fsx files to transform the AST results into human readable results.

```
val inline sprint_fol_formula : formula<fol> -> string
```

In the process of creating test cases we also output both the AST result and the human readable result.

The AST result is the result of processing the formulas. To transform the AST into human readable format in the unit test we just use `sprint_fol_formula astResult`.

Now if the result is `formula<fol> list` instead of `formula<fol>`, the correct result will be output when using FSI, but `sprint_fol_formula` does not accept `formula<fol> list`.

The only reasonable answer I can conclude for the difference is that `fsi.AddPrinter` has the built-in ability to take a list apart and then print each type individually.

Is this true, or did I miss something?

If this is true, can you add a refernce where this is documented.

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx) by Don Syme seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is quite simple. There is a printer for `'a list`, which prints each element in the list (or only the first ones, depending on their textual lengths and the list's length), and formats it nicely (`[ _; _; _; ... ]`. When prints the items, it uses **your** printer.

Comment: Do you now where this is documented?

Comment: That is how all the printers of generic data structures are implemented (and a similar method is used for `printf`, and less commonly `.ToString`). I do not know of specific documentation for the various built-in printers. I guess you could look at the source code.