# F# Type printers: Standards and quality examples of type printers

Tags: printing, f#, printf, standards

As a follow-on to [F# fsi.AddPrinter: Does AddPrinter have ability to take list apart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13893375/1243762)

I was not aware that type printers should provide for handling a list as input.

As such, are there any published standards for what is/should be required of a type printer?

Can you please provide references to examples of such code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was not aware that type printers should provide for handling a list as input.

I advise you not to do so. If you do it, you break KISS principle and may surprise other team members with a strange way of displaying very standard `'T list`. Just provide a printer for `'T` and let F# Interactive figure out the rest.

You may consider this case

```
type Theorem = Axiom list
```

where you care about `Theorem` and would like to display it in an appropriate way. Then it makes sense to define a printer so that a `Theorem` is printed out as

```
:- axiom 1, axiom 2, ..., axiom n.
```

This example isn't a very good example because you probably prefer a type-safe solution

```
type Theorem = Theorem of Axiom list
```

That said, you may ask whether you should go for `fsi.AddPrinter` at all. The `fsi.AddPrinter` bits may be there due to legacy reasons. More universal solutions are to override `ToString()` methods and to use [StructuredFormatDisplay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx) attribute in order that you have good printers for both `fsc` and `fsi`, which work with `printf "%A"`, `printf "%O"`, etc.